# Get Count in List of instances contained in a string

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have a string containing up to 9 *unique* numbers from 1 to 9 (myString) e.g. "12345"

I have a list of strings {"1"}, {"4"} (myList) .. and so on.

I would like to know how many instances in the string (myString) are contained within the list (myList), in the above example this would return 2.

so something like

```
count = myList.Count(myList.Contains(myString));
```

I could change myString to a list if required.

Thanks very much

Joe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
count = mylist.Count(s => myString.Contains(s));
```

Answer (score 6):

It is not perfectly clear what you need, but these are some options that could help:

```
myList.Where(s => s == myString).Count()
```

or

```
myList.Where(s => s.Contains(myString)).Count()
```

the first would return the number of strings in the list that are the same as yours, the second would return the number of strings that contain yours. If neither works, please make your question more clear.

Comment: Better to use `myList.Count(s => s.Contains(myString))` because its more optimum.

Answer (score 1):

If `myList` is just `List<string>`, then this should work:

```
int count = myList.Count(x => myString.Contains(x));
```

If `myList` is `List<List<string>>`:

```
int count = myList.SelectMany(x => x).Count(s => myString.Contains(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach, but it's limited to 1 character matches. For your described scenario of numbers from 1-9 this works fine. Notice the `s[0]` usage which refers to the list items as a character. For example, if you had "12" in your list, it wouldn't work correctly.

```
string input = "123456123";
var list = new List<string> { "1", "4" };
var query = list.Select(s => new
                {
                    Value = s,
                    Count = input.Count(c => c == s[0])
                });

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} occurred {1} time(s)", item.Value, item.Count);
}
```

For multiple character matches, which would correctly count the occurrences of "12", the `Regex` class comes in handy:

```
var query = list.Select(s => new
                {
                    Value = s,
                    Count = Regex.Matches(input, s).Count
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
count = myList.Count(s => s==myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var count = myList.Count(x => myString.ToCharArray().Contains(x[0]));
```

this will only work if the item in myList is a single digit

**Edit:** as you probably noticed this will convert myString to a char array multiple times so it would be better to have

```
var myStringArray = myString.ToCharArray();
var count = myList.Count(x => myStringArray.Contains(x[0]));
```